# How to Copy and paste visible cells (FILTERED TABLE CELLS) to a CSV

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-csv

I want to copy and paste from one excel to another using copy and paste visible cells only as I have a filtered table between a set range.

I'd like to do this through save CSV but apparently this is not possible.  The code below works but it doesn't seem to copy paste visible cells/filtered cells like I'd like.

Thanks in advance.  Or if there's another recommended way for getting filtered tables to a CSV I'd love to hear how.  Cheers.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'

 Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

With tbl.ListColumns(3).Range
    lastRow = .Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Cells(1), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
End With


Sheet1.Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Range("A2")


    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\teaz\Videos\CSV", FileFormat:= _
        xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="C:\Users\teaz\Videos" & Test1Str & " " & TestStr & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Application.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False




End Sub
```

Comment: Hilariously I resolved this by pasting into a notepad.  Surely this isn't a viable solution?  Hahaha #excel problems.  What would a non notepad solution be out of curiosity.

Comment: `I'd like to do this through save CSV but apparently this is not possible.` Says  who? :)

Comment: Wait it is?  Like everyone I talked to told me it was not possible to get a filtered excel table and save it to a CSV.   It is possible!?  Arghh lmao

Comment: @SiddharthRout Can you at least point me in the right direction.  Looks like I might go back to looking at my original vba code xD.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The problem I found was I had a filtered table in an excel and when I'd save that as CSV, the CSV would completely forget that there was filtered data and display it all.  I could not find anywhere how to get the CSV to read filtered only.  I'd be amazed if you found a workaround.  I've been fiddling around with this excel file all day xD

Comment: Logic `1` Filter the data `2` Add a new workbook `3` Copy filtered data to the new workbook. `4` Save new workbook as csv :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout  OHHH yeah I was kinda trying to do that above.  But when I copied it the copied excel would copy it all and not copy the filtered data and now I'm stuck xD

Comment: if you search stackoverflow, there are lot of posts which show you how to create a new workbbook. or how to copy filtered range from one workbook to another

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'll take a look.  I thought the above would work.  Maybe whats wrong with the above is there is no paste special.  I mean other than that it does work.  I do wonder why it doesn't copy just the filter data though.  I did include SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _

Comment: And if all else fails.  NOTEPAD XD

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sound advice.  Someone else had the same query on filtered data.  Used their code and ggwp.  No notepad needed.

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to post that code here and accept that as an answer so that it can help future visitors like yourself :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Alrighty, well anyone who has the same problem can see the answer now.  My code could work I saw there was an error when  I retried it but then again, the code below in the answer section will work with no fixes needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Copy all previously filtered data from all worksheets to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227710/copy-all-previously-filtered-data-from-all-worksheets-to-another)

```
Sub CopyFilteredDataToNewWorkbook()

    Dim newBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rowoffsetcount As Long
    Dim newsht As Excel.Worksheet

    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets is the same as the Sheets or Worksheets object, but more explicit
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' Get the used rows and columns
        Set rng = sht.UsedRange

        ' Offset the range so it starts at row 15
        rowoffsetcount = 15 - rng.Row
        Set rng = rng.Offset(rowoffsetcount)

        ' Check there will be something to copy
        If (rng.Rows.Count - rowoffsetcount > 0) Then

            ' Reduce the number of rows in the range so it ends at the same row
            Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - rowoffsetcount)

            ' Check that there is a sheet we can copy it to
            On Error Resume Next
            Set newsht = Nothing
            Set newsht = newBook.Worksheets(sht.Index)
            On Error GoTo 0

            ' We have run out of sheets, add another at the end
            If (newsht Is Nothing) Then
                Set newsht = newBook.Sheets.Add(, newBook.Worksheets(newBook.Worksheets.Count))
            End If

            ' Give it the same name
            newsht.Name = sht.Name

            ' Get the range of visible (i.e. unfiltered) rows
            ' (can't do this before the range resize as that doesn't work on disjoint ranges)
            Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            ' Paste the visible data into the new sheet
            rng.Copy newsht.Range("A1")

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is your problem:

```
'/* you only worked on Range("A2") */
Sheet1.Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

You should access your `tbl` object like:

```
'/* this will give you the entire filtered table body */
tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Similarly, you can use:

```
Sheet1.Range("YourTableName").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

And lastly, avoid all objects with `Active` prefix (e.g. `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveWindow`). You already know how to assign variables, then be consistent about it.

Comment: Hmmm, I did try your solution and I guess it would be less error prone but still my resulting table in the CSV gives me unfiltered Data still.  I have not included something like .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).paste though.  Maybe thats where I went wrong.